# Creating weapon classes and a Combat Class

Tags: java, arrays, class, random

I am creating a text based game and I am having some issues.. This is what I have so far.  So far I have a Combat Class, and two Classes for two different Weapons.  I am trying to assign hit points to the weapons themselves.  But my biggest issue is in the Combat class.  I am trying to create it to were there will be random weapon drops at random times and also random Weapons.  So far in the Combat class I have this:

```
public class Combat {
    final int chanceOfDrop = 3;
    static Weapons[] wepArray = {new M4(), new M16()}
    static boolean[] hasWeapon = {false, true};

    public static int  ranNumberGen(int chanceOfDrop) {
        return (int) (Math.random()*1); 
    }

    private void enemyDead() {
        boolean canDrop = false;
        if(ranNumberGen(chanceOfDrop)==0){
            canDrop = true;

        }

        if(canDrop == true){
            givePlayerWeapon(Weapon[Combat.ranNumberGen(Weapons.length)]);
        }

        private static void givePlayerWeapon(int w) {
            hasWeapon[w] = true;

            for w <(Weapons.length-1) {
                if has weapon[w] {
                    System.out.println(wepArray[w].getWeaponName);
                }
                }
        }
    }

    }
}
```

I have issues when I am creating the new M4(), and the new M16() it says Type mismatch: cannot convert form M4 to Weapons.  I do have a class named Weapons, could that be the problem?

And here is my M4 Class, both M4 and M16 Classes are identical

```
public abstract class M4 {
  private Integer weaponDamage = 5;
  private Integer weaponAmmo = 25;
  private String weaponName = "M4";

  public M4(String name, int ammo, int damage) {
    name = weaponName;
    ammo = weaponAmmo;
    damage = weaponDamage;
  }

  public String getWeaponName() {
    return weaponName;
  }

  public Integer getAmmo() {
    return weaponAmmo;
  }

  public Integer getDamage() {
    return weaponDamage;
  }
}
```

I don't think I have any issues here.  Maybe my problem lies within this though.  Although, I have a Weapons class, but nothing in it.  Do I need that?

Comment: Lots of issues here. Why is `M4` abstract? Why doesn't it extend or implement `Weapon`? You seem to use `Weapon` and `Weapons` interchangeably – which is it? You also seem to use `Weapons` when you mean `wepArray`.

Comment: I agree with @Matt. This code doesn't even appear to be compilable.

Comment: I would create an Interface named Weapon, then have each specific class implement the Weapon class. That would allow each one to have a method to get and set the random value. Especially since you said these classes are almost identical. That's a perfect opportunity to create an interface.

Comment: Ah I see.  I talked to a friend of mine not too long ago and he told me that I should make the M4 Class abstract.  And It doesnt implement Weapon, because I have nothing in the Weapon class for it to implement.  He told me to just make a separate class for each weapon.  So would I need to insert wepArray where weapon is at the givePlayerWeapon? And at Weapons.legnth?

Comment: You need to look at this before you start programming Java. This is not Visual Basic. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep take your time and read the whole thing.

Comment: Folks are right, but +1 purely for intention of creating a text game :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things to fix at first sight:

- Create a generic Weapon class that defines some properties that apply to each weapon, like name, damage, ammo, scope multiplier, etc... Then create subclasses for Weapon, like M4 and M16, that specify the properties and eventually add weapon-specific properties.
- Add brackets to this line:

  ```
  System.out.println(wepArray[w].getWeaponName); // Change to getWeaponName()
  ```
- Remove the `abstract` keyword from M4.
- Fix the ranNumberGen method because it will always return 0 right now. `Math.random()` returns a float in the range [0,1[. This means that casting it to an int will always result in 0. Multiply it by *n* to have a random int in the range of [0, *n*[. You probably want this:

  ```
  public static int ranNumberGen(int max) {
      return (int) (Math.random() * max); 
  }
  ```
- Change this line:

  ```
  givePlayerWeapon(Weapon[Combat.ranNumberGen(Weapons.length)]);
  ```

  to:

  ```
  givePlayerWeapon(wepArray[Combat.ranNumberGen(wepArray.length)]);
  ```
- The syntax of a `for`-loop is like this:

  ```
  for (variable-initialization; condition; increment)
  ```

  So in your case, you want:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < hasWeapon.length; ++i)
  {
      if (hasWeapon[i]) System.out.println(wepArray[i].getWeaponName());
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to revisit your decision to use an inheritance-style heirarchy for game objects before it is too late.

In practice, I've found a component-entity model and/or prototype model to be much more effective. You could take a look at the code in my old Java roguelike game Tyrant for inspiration:

- Weapon definitions: mikera/tyrant/Weapon.java (Github is down right now so can't find the exact link, but should be easy enough to Google)

The idea is that you make your objects by setting properties / composing compoenents in a Map-like game object rather than using static inheritance.

When you want to create a random weapon in this model, you can just get a list of all the possible weapon prototypes, and clone one of them at random to make a new weapon.

Answer (score 0):

the mean of abstract in "public abstract class M4" is that you cannot make a new object with this class.
So you can put all commons fields of your weapons in the weapon class and make m4 and m16 extends the weapon and you code would compile.